# pdb breakpoint isn't firing on an explicit file

Tags: python, pdb

**Question:** What have I done wrong with my break point?

**What I've tried so far:**
[Attempting to figure out a bug with distlib](https://github.com/brettcannon/caniusepython3/issues/87) I'm trying to get a breakpoint to fire in `distlib.metadata.Metadata.get_requirements`. In a python3.4 interpreter I've run

```
(Pdb) import distlib.metadata
(Pdb) b distlib.metadata.Metadata.get_requirements
Breakpoint 7 at /Users/alexlord/.virtualenvs/porting_authority/lib/python3.4/site-    packages/distlib/metadata.py:844
(Pdb) meta_data.get_requirements(['uttt'], set())
*** TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

but the breakpoint doesn't fire as I expected.

**Full Stack Trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                               
  File "/home/alex/.virtualenvs/caniusepython3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/distlib-0.2.0-py3.4.egg/distlib/metadata.py", line 874, in get_requirements                                                  
    result.extend(d['requires'])                                                                    
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**Context**

Here's the bug I'm attempting to figure out.

```
from distlib.database import Metadata
meta_data = Metadata()
meta_data.get_requirements(['uttt'], set()) # Valid pypi package, ultimate tick tack toe =P
```

Comment: "but the breakpoint doesn't fire as I expected." -- what did you expect?

Comment: I expected the first line of the function to cause a break. I attempted to assign a specific line numbers but that caused  a file not found error.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error you're getting, it might contain clues.

Comment: There is no trace. This is the full error string and I get a blank line as a return after `meta_data.get_requirements` using pdb.

Comment: If you don't get it work just hardcode import pdb ; pdb.set_trace() into the file. Also I suggest checking out ipdb (you get a fancier prompt) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb